# Issue implementing sobel operator

Tags: c++, image-processing, sobel

I am trying to implement the [sobel operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobel_operator) in C++. I am inputting and outputting non-compressed PPM files (P3). My code is below.

To quickly outline the sobel operator, I convert an input file to grayscale, run a convolution operation to get an x- and y-gradient value, find its magnitude, and for each pixel, if the difference between the magnitude and the original grayscale value is greater than a threshold, it is an edge pixel.

I have file-writes after each step so that I can verify output and I know that the algorithm works until the grayscale part. On an image like this:

[image: Original image]

my output is

[image: Broken sobel]

It seems like my code is creating "phantom" CDs and objects for whatever reason. I've verified the code that I use for my convolution and I believe it to be correct but something is obviously going wrong. Any help would be appreciated!

```
#include <fstream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <time.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <tuple>
#include <iterator>
#include <climits>  // Max_int for shortest distance
#include <limits>
#include <chrono>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <cmath>
#include <sstream>

std::vector<std::vector<std::tuple<int, int, int>>> image;
std::vector<std::vector<int>> imageGray;
std::vector<std::vector<int>> imageGradX;
std::vector<std::vector<int>> imageGradY;
std::vector<std::vector<int>> imageBinary;

int THRESHOLD;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::string inFileName = argv[1];
    std::ifstream inputFile(inFileName);
    int sizex;
    int sizey;
    if (inputFile.is_open())
    {
        std::string inFormat, max;
        inputFile >> inFormat;
        inputFile >> sizex;
        inputFile >> sizey;
        inputFile >> max;

        for (int indexX = 0; indexX < sizex; indexX++)
        {
            std::vector<std::tuple<int, int, int>> temp;
            for (int indexY = 0; indexY < sizey; indexY++)
            {
                int valRed, valGreen, valBlue;
                inputFile >> valRed;
                inputFile >> valGreen;
                inputFile >> valBlue;
                temp.push_back(std::make_tuple(valRed, valGreen, valBlue));
            }
            image.push_back(temp);
        }
    }
    inputFile.close();

    // Make image grayscale
    for(std::vector<std::vector<std::tuple<int, int, int>>>::iterator it = image.begin(); it != image.end(); ++it)
    {
        std::vector<int> temp;
        //it is now a pointer to a vector<int>
        for (std::vector<std::tuple<int, int, int>>::iterator jt = it->begin(); jt != it->end(); ++jt)
        {
            temp.push_back((std::get<0>(*jt) + std::get<1>(*jt) + std::get<2>(*jt)) / 3);
        }
        imageGray.push_back(temp);
    }

    std::ofstream filegrayppm;
  filegrayppm.open("outgray.ppm");
  filegrayppm << "P3 " << sizex << " " << sizey << " 255\n";
  for(std::vector<std::vector<int>>::iterator it = imageGray.begin(); it != imageGray.end(); ++it)
  {
  //it is now a pointer to a vector<int>
  for (std::vector<int>::iterator jt = it->begin(); jt != it->end(); ++jt)
  {
          filegrayppm << *jt << " " << *jt << " " << *jt << " ";
  }
  filegrayppm << "\n";
  }
  filegrayppm.close();

    // Sobel operator
    for (int i = 0; i < sizex; i++)
    {
        std::vector<int> tempX;
        std::vector<int> tempY;
        for (int j = 0; j < sizey; j++)
        {
            if (i == 0 || j == 0 || i >= sizex - 1 || j >= sizey - 1)
            {
                tempX.push_back(0);
                tempY.push_back(0);
            }
            else
            {
                int newValX = imageGray.at(i + 1).at(j + 1) + imageGray.at(i - 1).at(j + 1) + (2 * imageGray.at(i).at(j + 1)) - imageGray.at(i - 1).at(j - 1) - (2 * imageGray.at(i).at(j - 1)) - imageGray.at(i + 1).at(j-1);
                int newValY = imageGray.at(i - 1).at(j - 1) + imageGray.at(i - 1).at(j + 1) + (2 * imageGray.at(i - 1).at(j)) - imageGray.at(i + 1).at(j - 1) - imageGray.at(i + 1).at(j + 1) - (2 * imageGray.at(i + 1).at(j));
                tempX.push_back(newValX);
                tempY.push_back(newValY);
            }
        }
        imageGradX.push_back(tempX);
        imageGradY.push_back(tempY);
    }

    std::ofstream filesobelppm;
    filesobelppm.open("outsobel.ppm");
    filesobelppm << "P3 " << sizex << " " << sizey << " 255\n";
    for(std::vector<std::vector<int>>::iterator it = imageGradX.begin(); it != imageGradX.end(); ++it)
    {
    //it is now a pointer to a vector<int>
    for (std::vector<int>::iterator jt = it->begin(); jt != it->end(); ++jt)
    {
            filesobelppm << *jt << " " << *jt << " " << *jt << " ";
    }
    filesobelppm << "\n";
    }
    filesobelppm.close();

    std::ofstream filesobelyppm;
    filesobelyppm.open("outsobely.ppm");
    filesobelyppm << "P3 " << sizex << " " << sizey << " 255\n";
    for(std::vector<std::vector<int>>::iterator it = imageGradY.begin(); it != imageGradY.end(); ++it)
    {
    //it is now a pointer to a vector<int>
    for (std::vector<int>::iterator jt = it->begin(); jt != it->end(); ++jt)
    {
            filesobelyppm << *jt << " " << *jt << " " << *jt << " ";
    }
    filesobelyppm << "\n";
    }
    filesobelyppm.close();

    THRESHOLD = 20;

    // Generate binary image
    // imageBinary
    for (int i = 0; i < sizex; i++)
    {
        std::vector<int> temp;
        for (int j = 0; j < sizey; j++)
        {
            int magnitude = sqrt((imageGradX.at(i).at(j) * imageGradX.at(i).at(j)) + (imageGradY.at(i).at(j) * imageGradY.at(i).at(j)));
//             if (imageGray[i][j] - magnitude > THRESHOLD)
            if (abs(imageGray.at(i).at(j) - magnitude) > THRESHOLD)
                temp.push_back(1);
            else
                temp.push_back(0);
        }
        imageBinary.push_back(temp);
    }

    // Write out
    std::ofstream fileppm;
    fileppm.open("out.ppm");
    fileppm << "P3 " << sizex << " " << sizey << " 1\n";
    for(std::vector<std::vector<int>>::iterator it = imageBinary.begin(); it != imageBinary.end(); ++it)
    {
        //it is now a pointer to a vector<int>
        for (std::vector<int>::iterator jt = it->begin(); jt != it->end(); ++jt)
        {
            if (*jt == 1)
                fileppm << "0 0 0 ";
            else
                fileppm << "1 1 1 ";
        }
        fileppm << "\n";
    }
    fileppm.close();
}
```

Comment: Split your monster main into smaller functions and test that these do what you intend. It is useless blob of code like it is right now anyway, no wonder that it produces garbage.

Comment: The Sobel operator does not compare to the input image. Simply compute the magnitude. You can threshold the magnitude if you need a binary output.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I have tried this but I still get "phantom" objects appearing (generally) to the right.

Comment: My comment was just to indicate the error in your intended output. I'm sure you have some indexing issue somewhere, but you've posted too much code to read, see [mre] for hints on how to improve your question.

Comment: You should also consider not encoding an image as a vector or vectors, it's highly inefficient. Using `push_back` to write to the output image is not only inefficient, but also makes it hard to see where the written data ends up. Allocate an output array and write to it using indexing. And use a 1D array indexed as `x + y*width` or similar for more efficient image manipulation.